# Use all system memory in Solaris

Tags: shell, solaris, memory, perl

I am doing server testing and intentionally trying to crash a virtual Solaris server by using all memory. Server has a ulimit of 15 GB (several hundred GB of total system/swap memory). Is there a straight forward way of doing this using a shell/Perl script? (This is in a hardened/secured environment so the only accessable tool is Perl [and shell of course]).

Background: What is actually being tested is failover of essential processes to another server. Lately we have been having a number of processes "go out of control" and consume all system resources thus causing server to crash (separate issue). I am trying to create a simple repeatable scenario to test the response to this situation.

Comment: To avoid crossposting, see my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806990/use-all-system-memory-in-solaris#13811917

Comment: What does `ulimit -aH` tell you?

Answer (score 3):

jlliagre answered the question.  And posted a link to a good answer.  Credit him, not me.

When you write to /tmp, in Solaris only - you are writing to RAM not to disk.  This is why writes to /tmp files go super fast.  Once RAM fills up the system will come to a crawl.  If you completely fill /tmp, then writews to /tmp will attempt to write to swap, and eventually the system falls over. This approach bypasses ulimit for memory.  Be sure you do not have a max file size specified:

```
ulimit -a
file(blocks)         unlimited
```